# PHP Zipped contents appearing in "_" underscore directory

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to zip a series of files into a zip file without any directories. Just the files. The problem is the resulting Zip file has all the files inside a directory that is named `_`. I have no idea where this directory is coming from. Here is my code for creating the Zip file:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($filepath, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($tempPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);
/** @var SplFileInfo $file */
foreach ($files as $file) {
   if (!$file->isDir()) {
        $zip->addFile($file->getRealPath(), basename($file->getFilename()));
   }
}
zip->close();
```

I supposed that `$file->getFilename()` would be enough to place the file in the root level of the zip file, but added a `basename` since that wasn't working. I can't get it to place the files in the root of the zip file and not create a directory `_` to put them in. No idea where that underscore directory is coming from.

In case it makes a difference the files are taken from a location linked by a symbolic link. On an Ubuntu server.

Anyone know what's going on and how it can be fixed?

[Here's an example of the output zip file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3ZjlpymJxJmrfo4U3_J3EKxG45onSoy/view?usp=sharing) Interestingly in Google's preview it appears correct, but if you open it in a zip viewer like Windows' default extractor or 7zip, the files are all in a `_` directory.

I use these zips in an application called Anki and it appears this application also detects them in the subdirectory. Something's wrong here but I'm not able to figure out what...

Comment: What is the value of `$filepath`

Comment: It's something similar to `/path/storage/directory/app/`. It's where the zip file gets saved. It is saving correctly in that location. It just is not inserting the files correctly in the root of the zip file.

Comment: Sorry for asking but, have you inspected the values of the variables involved (either with a step debugger or with plain `var_dump()`), esp. `basename($file->getFilename())`, and compared them with the actual output?

Comment: Right, I did debug it and  `basename($file->getFilename())` gives just the filename, wihout any path or subdirectory.

Comment: Another guess... How are you inspecting the resulting ZIP file? Is it possible that the `_` root level directory is an abstraction of some GUI program? Can you maybe add a screenshot to the question?

Comment: Good point. I tried opening the zip in both Windows' default zip viewer and in 7zip and the underscore folder is present in both of them. But I uploaded the zip to Google Drive and in the preview there it is not present. So something is wrong with the zip file, but it appears some viewers are able to avoid the problem while others are not. The application I want to use this with (Anki) also sees the underscore folder, and that causes it to fail.

Comment: In the meantime while I'm trying to figure out this problem, I've created a hacky "fix" - instead of adding the file to the zip, I get the contents with `file_get_contents` and then create a new file with those contents directly in the zip. It's probably a lot of extra overhead but it works...

Comment: All the entries in your sample ZIP file have a leading slash (`/`). If you reproduce it intentionally you get the same results (see [this note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) in a Python library: "A leading slash in the filename may lead to the archive being impossible to open in some zip programs on Windows systems."). The impossible bit is that [basename()](https://php.net/basename) should not produce slashes at all. It's either some mojibake issue I cannot grasp, or I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an output filename.

```
'/path/storage/directory/app/myZipfile.zip'
```

This code worked correctly for me.  It gave me a zip file with only the files, no subfolder inside

```
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__ );
$tempPath = $filepath . "/objects";
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip_opened = $zip->open( $filepath . "/test.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE );

if( $zip_opened == true )
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $tempPath ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY );
    foreach( $files as $file )
    {
        if( !$file->isDir() )
        {
            $zip->addFile( $file->getRealPath(), basename( $file->getFilename() ) );
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
} else {
    var_dump( "Could not open zip file" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand what that has to do with the problem. I provide a valid output filename and the zip file is output correctly. Its the contents of the zip file that are incorrectly placed in a subdirectory that shouldn't exist.

Comment: I edited the post above.  Works correctly for me

Comment: I don't know either what this answer is trying to illustrate. The code in the question doesn't have any obvious flaw.